# Error al instalar Sharp Node JS

Tags: nodejs, reactjs

Queria saber si podian ayudarme, estoy intentando instalar Sharp en node js , lo instalo pero cuando ejecuto el servidor me aparece lo siguiente: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguno sabe que puede ser?
Los pasos que hice fueron los siguientes:

1. "npm i sharp"
2. "npm run start" (Sale el error de la imagen)
3. Instale donde dice posible solutions, es decir puse:
   "npm install --ignore-scripts=false --verbose sharp"
   "npm install --platform=win32 --arc=x64 sharp"
4. Vuelvo a poner "npm run start", y vuelve a salir el mismo error

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Punto 4 especialmente :)

Comment: @fredyfx ahi lo formule, decime si entendes porfavor

Comment: Vale, solo 2 preguntas: ¿Versión de node js instalada? ¿Versión de npm instalada?

Comment: @fredyfx mis versiones son:
Node.js v14.17.4.
npm@6.14.14

Comment: ¿Alguna novedad de tu escenario?

Comment: @fredyfx Que tal? Lo resolvi creando una carpeta public , no pude instalar Sharp. Formule una pregunta hace unos dias y no supieron responderme o al menos alguien que sepa no lo vio, te envio el link me decis por favor si tenes idea como solucionarlo ? 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/483099/react-js-node-js-y-mercadopago

Comment: No entiendo, ¿lograste resolver esta pregunta o no? Si lo lograste, te invito a colocar la respuesta en la parte inferior indicando los pasos que hiciste para darle solución, serás el héroe de más usuarios que tengan el mismo caso o algo similar. Por otro lado, para Mercado-Pago, supuestamente hay gente que trabaja ahí y tienen cuentas en SOes y ayudan a resolver esas preguntas. Saludos :D

Comment: Perfecto, si logre resolverlo ahi debajo coloco la solucion que tuve, por otro lado, como es eso del SOes? Necesito integrar mercado pago, muchas gracias @fredyfx

Comment: SOes = StackOverflow en ESpañol. Seguro alguien te responderá en algún momento, hay bastantes preguntas con la etiqueta Mercado-Pago, masbien, entra a la sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol y ahí puedes conversar libremente de esos temas.

Comment: Muchas gracias @fredyx , hay alguna forma de darte honores o puntos?

Comment: Un gusto colaborar. La gratitud que tienes hacia mi persona es un honor para mi :)

Answer (score 2):

De la documentación oficial de: https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

```
Common problems

The architecture and platform of Node.js used for npm install must be the same as the architecture and platform of Node.js used at runtime. See the cross-platform section if this is not the case.

When using npm v6 or earlier, the npm install --unsafe-perm flag must be used when installing as root or a sudo user.

When using npm v7, the user running npm install must own the directory it is run in.

The npm install --ignore-scripts=false flag must be used when npm has been configured to ignore installation scripts.

Check the output of running npm install --verbose sharp for useful error messages.
```

Dice que si estás utilizando la versión 6 de npm, el comando a ejecutar es:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm
```

Y que ese comando lo ejecutes con permisos de administrador.

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo error, no se que podra ser

Comment: borra la carpeta de `node_modules` y vuelve a intentar :) Si te sigue dando error, ejecuta `npm install --verbose sharp` y agrega esa información a tu pregunta.